# Remove a 'Deny' rule (permission) from the 'UserChoice' key in the Registry via C#

Tags: c#, security, registry, registrykey

I am working on File Associations. I have identified that there is a key called `UserChoice` in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\[ext].
```

I have been able to read from and write to the `UserChoice` key provided that *I* create it and that it has *not* already been created by Windows. However, if the `UserChoice` key *has* already been created by Windows, then I need to run as Administrator to get access to the key. My ultimate goal is to *delete* the `UserChoice` key.

I have noted that Windows places a **Deny** rule on the `UserChoice` key which is preventing me from deleting that key. If I can succeed in removing that rule, I believe that I'll be able to delete the `UserChoice` key. Here is the code that I have tried:

```
public static void ShowSecurity(RegistryKey regKeyRoot, string user) {
    RegistrySecurity security = regKeyRoot.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);

    foreach (RegistryAccessRule ar in
        security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount))) {

        if (ar.IdentityReference.Value.Contains(User) &&
                ar.AccessControlType.ToString().ToLower() == "deny") {

            security.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific(ar);
            regKeyRoot.SetAccessControl(security);
        }
    }
}
```

When Windows creates the `UserChoice` key it adds a security rule for the current user of Type **Deny; permission: Special**. This rule is not inherited and applies to the `UserChoice` key only.

With some messing about and running as Administrator I am able to access that `RegistryAccessRule`. However even running as Administrator, I cannot remove this rule. I have read somewhere in my research that there is not a programmatic way to do it. I can remove this rule via RegEdit. I can also remove the `UserChoice` key using File Types Manager from NirSoft. So I *assume* there is some way to do this.

**Summary:** Is there a way that I can remove the Deny rule so that I can delete the `UserChoice` key?

Comment: Anyone found a way to do this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not so far as I know.  I have done some more work on it but I think it will need unmanaged code..........

Comment: @ScruffyDuck Your code is definitely on the right track. Your code and the revised code provided in [the answer by ali](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28268069/1497596) lead me to success. It is *not* necessary to resort to unmanaged code. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41290208/1497596).

Answer (score 2):

Your code example and the revisions suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268069/1497596) by @ali lead me to a solution for overcoming the security setting that Windows places on the `UserChoice` key which enabled me to delete that key.

My solution presumes that the `UserChoice` key is present in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (`HKCU`) hive. If that is the case, the user *owns* the `UserChoice` key and therefore has the necessary privileges to change the security settings on that key and ultimately delete it. (This means that the user does *not* need to be a member of the Administrators group.)

The `extensionKey` parameter of this method is the parent key of the `UserChoice` key.

```cs
static void DeleteUserChoiceKey(RegistryKey extensionKey)
{
    const string userChoiceKeyName = "UserChoice";

    using (RegistryKey userChoiceKey =
        extensionKey.OpenSubKey(userChoiceKeyName,
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree,
            RegistryRights.ChangePermissions))
    {
        if (userChoiceKey == null) { return; }
        string userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        RegistrySecurity security = userChoiceKey.GetAccessControl();

        AuthorizationRuleCollection accRules =
            security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

        foreach (RegistryAccessRule ar in accRules)
        {
            if (ar.IdentityReference.Value == userName &&
                ar.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
            {
                security.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific(ar); // remove the 'Deny' permission
            }
        }

        userChoiceKey.SetAccessControl(security); // restore all original permissions
                                                  // *except* for the 'Deny' permission
    }

    extensionKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(userChoiceKeyName, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick thought. Does it work if you take ownership og the regKey, before changing the rules on it

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit please?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void ShowSecurity(RegistryKey regKeyRoot, string user) 
{

regKeyRoot.OpenSubKey("", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree,
                    RegistryRights.ChangePermissions);

RegistrySecurity security = regKeyRoot.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);

security.SetGroup( new NTAccount("Administrators") );
security.SetOwner( new NTAccount("ali") ); //Your account name
security.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);
regKeyRoot.SetAccessControl(security);

//---------

  foreach (RegistryAccessRule ar in security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount))) 
  {
    if (ar.IdentityReference.Value.Contains(User) && ar.AccessControlType ==  AccessControlType.Deny )
       security.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific(ar);
  }

regKeyRoot.SetAccessControl(security);


}
```