# Is there any way to programmatically set the "UserChoice" registry key to take over a file type association?

Tags: c#, security, registry, default, file-type

I have been trying to find a way to change the default file association for a
specific file extension in windows 7. I have an app that is used to view .tif
files that I want to prompt th user if its not the default viewer for that file
type. If they choose to make it the default, I want to override the current
default viewer. This works fine if there are no other viewers installed on the
system. When there is another viewer that has been selected by the user, I
cannot change the registry key that controls that here:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.tif\UserChoice
```

I have scoured the web trying to find someone that has done this, but nobody
seems to have any answers. When I try to update the "Progid" value within this
key, I get a "Cannot write to the registry key" or "Requested registry access is
not allowed" errors. The code is simple enough:

```
var path = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.tif\UserChoice";
var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path, true);
key.SetValue("Progid", "myprogid...");
```

Is there some special protection on this key that prevents it from being
programmatically edited?

Comment: Have you tried updating it, for example in a console application, which you run with administrator privileges?

Comment: It is a desktop app, running as myself but without admin privileges. That was my next step.

Comment: Running as administrator did not help.

Comment: Are you looking for this function? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776332(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The question ["Remove a 'Deny' rule (permission) from the 'UserChoice' key in the Registry via C#"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6108128/1497596) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41290208/1497596) to it might help.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to write to the key UserChoice you needed to take ownership of the key before writing to it (like [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/170289-46-programmatically-inheritable-permissions) code - not in c# (C++), but I assume it can be done the same way).

You will be able to write to the key, and your file association code will works !

EDIT : See also [Registry Key Security and Access Rights on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This link may have more information for you: [How do I take ownership of a Registry Key using C# and these: RegOpenKeyEx and RegSetKeySecurity??](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/5e6780b0-30f1-42f5-af28-748b9b462009)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured out some way to do this try the [assoc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490865.aspx) and [ftype](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490912.aspx) command-line tools. Note though that you will need to run them with administrative privileges.

1. Create a batch script that uses `Assoc` and `Ftype` to set the file association.
2. Use [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to execute the batch script.

You basically have to create a .bat (or .cmd) file with the following lines:

```
ASSOC .txt=TXTFileWordPad    
FTYPE TXTFileWordPad="%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" %%1
```

For more information on how to use these tool have a look at: [Managing Files from the Command Line- Assoc and Ftype](http://commandwindows.com/assoc.htm).

Answer (score -1):

It seems not changeable but you can delete the `UserChoice`.